# Why low accuracy on randomly generated data with sklearn library

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have generated a normally distributed sample along with 3 classes to perform classification. I got very low accuracy. I was wondering if you could give me your valuable feedback to improve my LDA classifier's performance. I appreciate your time. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from random import seed
import random
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import time

seed(23)
mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 # mean and standard deviation
x1 = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
x1=x1.reshape(-1, 1)

seed(1)
y=np.random.randint(0,3,size=(1000,1))
y_cross=np.ravel(y)
start_time1 = time.time()
clf_s=LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
print('5-fold cross-validation accuracy score:', np.mean(cross_val_score(clf_s,x1, np.ravel(y), cv=5,scoring='accuracy')))
print('5-fold cross-validation F1 score:', np.mean(cross_val_score(clf_s, x1, np.ravel(y), cv=5,scoring='f1_micro')))
end_time1 = time.time()
print ("Computational time in seconds = " +str(end_time1 - start_time1) )
```

Results:

```
5-fold cross-validation accuracy score: 0.3280613765344133
5-fold cross-validation F1 score: 0.3280613765344133
Computational time in seconds = 1.4167194366455078
```

Comment: its low accuracy on random data - try it on some real-datasets online: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets

Comment: @RamshaSiddiqui  I wanted to use synthetic data to learn the behavior of the LDA sklearn implementation.

Answer (score 2):

.33 accuracy on 3 classes means pure guessing. I think it's expected as the labels you generated are random. The algo is supposed to uncover a structure in your data. The way you prepared your data means there is no structure for your algo to learn from. If you want higher accuracy generate your data properly, e.g with [sklearn.datasets.make_blobs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html) and train your algo on that dataset.

**Proof**

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

X,y = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, n_features=2, centers=3, random_state=42)

clf=LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
np.mean(cross_val_score(clf,X,y, cv=5,scoring='accuracy'))
1.0
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid using sklearn package to generate my data. I guess, my code failed to understand the data. Is there any way to improve the accuracy other than using sklearn generated data?

Comment: @Barsal There are many online data repositories for ML. Kaggle and UCI machine learning repository are some of them. Did my answer help you?